# How to Reduce width of Dash DataTable

Tags: python, datatable, plotly-dash

I have a dash.datatable like below a but the column width is too long for my values,
the column width should be limited to the maximum length word of the respective column.

my code:

```
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "A" : ["one","two","three"],
    "B" : ["one","two","three"],
    "C" : ["one","two","three"],
    
}
)
app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns],
    style_data={
        'whiteSpace': 'normal',
        'height': 'auto',
    },
    
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(mode="jupyterlab")
```

My DataTable looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the `DataTable` [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/reference) there is an argument `fill_width`:

> ... False: The table container's width will equal the width of its content.

Setting this argument to `False`:

```
app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns],
    style_data={
        'whiteSpace': 'normal',
        'height': 'auto',
    },
    fill_width=False
)
```

**Output:**

[image: Result]